# Add c wire to furnace for smart thermostat

Tags: electrical, furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, renovation

I have an older furnace and am looking to add a c wire for a smart thermostat.  Currently behind my thermostat I have red/black wire, however, there are 3 additional wires that are not connected.

At the furnace the red/black are connected (as shown below) and the 3 additional wires are free.

From what I understand the C wire is 24 volt common. I have metered the furnace running/not running and found a post transformer wire that is 24 volt constant.  Can I simply connect one of the spare wires to this terminal or is there potential for too much of a current draw blowing the transformer?

[image]

Red coil wire is from thermostat.
24v constant is the bottom right black wire (this is where I want to connect the C wire to)

Comment: What's the model number on that gas valve?

Comment: VR800C 1190 is the model number

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the terminal at the lower right in the photo is `C`.

Here's the wiring diagram from the documentation, which I highlighted in different colors.

[image]

Here's your wiring, which I highlighted using the same colors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will connect one of the spare wires to the TR and then to the C slot on thermostat.